# "Switching" text in labels

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have `Label` on my `Form`, for example:

```cs
lblUser.Text = "John";
```

I need the text to *change* when user *clicks on* it

```cs
private void lblUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUser.Text = "Mike";
}
```

So if user clicks again, the text should *changes* back. How I can switch this text *unlimited number of times*? Count of names can be *more than* `2`.
`Text` should be changed

```
John -> Mike -> Jack -> John -> Mike -> Jack -> John -> ...
```

and so on.

Comment: Where do you get the list of names? How we will know the order of names?

Comment: It's all about keeping state. You need a list of the names and the index of the last clicked. Then you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's organize available names into a collection (let it be an array):

```
private static string[] s_Names = new [] {
  "John", "Mike", "Jack", "Thomas",
};
```

then we can change name on `Click` with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;   

...

private void lblUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  lbUser.Text = s_Names
    .SkipWhile(name => name != lbUser.Text) // scroll up to the current name      
    .Skip(1)                                // skip current name
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? s_Names.First();   // restart if s_Names is exhausted
}
```

**Edit:** Same idea, *no Linq* solution (we are looking for index of current name add `1` and use modulo arithmetics to restart the sequence of names)

```
private void lblUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  lbUser.Text = s_Names[(Array.IndexOf(s_Names, lbUser.Text) + 1) % s_Names.Length];
}
```

Comment: Nice code, but im afraid OP could not understand a LINQ approach, maybe you could add an easier alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store the Names you want it to switch from (Or list if you want to add items at runetime):

```
private string[] Names = new string[]{"John","Mike"}; //Etc.
```

Now you want to store which name is being shown with an index:

```
private int NameIndex = 0;
```

Finally, you can iterate through the array whenever the button is clicked:

```
private void lblUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUser.Text = Names[NameIndex%Names.Length];
    NameIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Note the modulus operator. It gives you the remainder of a division, so NameIndex will never be larger or equal to Names.Length. In my code, it will create a sequence 0,1,0,1... etc. 2%2 = 0.

Comment: The solution works with multiple names. Depending on the length of the array, it will create a repeating sequence from 0...n where is the length of the array -1.

Comment: my bad, yes it will work, now that i read the code completely

Comment: The side effect of this is the `NameIndex` will keep increasing, eventually an overflow will occur depending on its datatype

Comment: I think if a user clicks the button 2 billion times, something else would break before that.. (maybe their mouse)

Answer (score 0):

checking the label and changing it based on the requirement.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = names.IndexOf(label1.Text);
            index = (index + 1) % (names.Count);
            label1.Text = names[index];
        }
```

Comment: This will not work if the list of names is more than 2, which is a requirement of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nameCounter = 0; // Variable to track displayed element
var usernameList = new List<string> { "John", "Mike", "Bill", "Andy" }; // list of values to cycle
lblUser.Text = usernameList[nameCounter++];
```

```
private void lblUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   nameCounter = nameCounter < usernameList.Count ? nameCounter : 0;
   lblUser.Text = usernameList[nameCounter++];
}
```

Comment: Modulo arithmetics is an alternative `nameCounter = (nameCounter + 1) % usernameList.Count;`

Comment: no; when *UI* involved the time required to *redraw* the control (`Label`) with all it's `Font`s (and *Bezier curves*), `Pen`s, `Brush`es will be much longer then remainder computation or ternary operation.

Comment: `lblUser.Text = usernameList[(++nameCounter) % usernameList.Count];`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, it's not case which require so many discussion.
I invite you to answer my questions if you know c # and UI so well. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have **just two names** that you want to switch you can do the bellow:

```cs
class Program {
        private const string nameOne = "John";
        private const string nameTwo = "Mike";

        private void lblUser_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (lblUser.Text == nameOne)
            {
                lblUser.Text = nameTwo;
            }else{
                lblUser.Text = nameOne;
            }
        }
    }
```